# Error in building project after installing VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed VS2012 on my system and VS2010 was already installed. I have a project made in VS2010 which was build successfully but later when i have installed VS2012 then it gives an error while build. Here is the error :

```
Error   430 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)' has some invalid arguments
```

I have searched on google and i found some of articles with the solution of this problem. All they have mentioned that either remove the  tags or remove the runat="server" from the table tag to solve this issue. I have tried and it worked for me.

But now my main concern is that i have more than 100 such pages and i don't want to remove it from each and every page. So is there any alternative solution to solve this issue. I mean to say can we handle this error in web.config or somewhere else so that i don't need to do it for every page.

If you have any idea then kindly suggest me and your suggestions will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this issue is nicely expalained in below link

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766115/value-of-type-system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmlgenericcontrol-cannot-be-converted-to-system-web-ui-htmlcontrols-htmltablerow

and you can apply a patch released by MS for this issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750147